# Angular2 bind value of map to checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, binding

I'm trying to bind the value of a map to html checkbox in angular2.

```
    this.profilType = new Map<string, boolean>();
    this.profilType.set("public", true);
```

to

```
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="profilType['public']"/>
```

I tried this before, but it caused errors.

```
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="profilType.get('public')"/>
```

Currently, no errors are displayed but it seems that there's no binding neither.

I found some solutions by using (click) mechanism but this are not relevant. Checkbox really need to react to component change.

Is there a way to do that or should I use different approach (advices are welcome too).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could only get the "banana in a box" syntax to work with getters/setters:

```
  get isPublic(): boolean {
    return this.profilType.get("public");
  }

  set isPublic(val: boolean) {
    this.profilType.set("public", val);
  }

  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isPublic" />
```

But you can call the map directly like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="profilType.get('public')" (ngModelChange)="profilType.set('public', $event)" />
```

Note that those getters will be called very often. If performance is an issue, you might be better off copying the boolean to/from the map using `ngModelChange`:

```
  this.isPublic = true;
  this.profilType.set("public", true);

  public setPublic() {
    this.profilType.set("public", this.isPublic);
  }

<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isPublic" (ngModelChange)="setPublic()" />
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to work fine for now. Of course, there is a lot of code to write more (getter/setter for each entry of map). It will allow to reduce a lot the html code by the way. Thanks Franck Modica. My rep is too low to rate you, sorry. I don't know if performance will be a issue here. I have very few feedback on this.

Comment: I updated my example to show you can call the map directly: `<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="profilType.get('public')" (ngModelChange)="profilType.set('public', $event)" />`. Less getters/setters, but more HTML.

Comment: It works perfectly. I tried a similar solution at first, but I let parenthesis [(ngModel)] instead of [ngModel]. It caused a lot of error hard to read for a beginner as I am. Thanks again.

Comment: @chd, since this answer solved your issue, kindly accept the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of the answer :)